# Can't fetch a number populated dynamically from a webpage after following some steps

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I've created a script using requests module and BeautifulSoup library to fetch some tabular content from a webpage. To generate the table it is necessary to follow the steps manually that I've shown in the image attached. The code that I've pasted below is a working one but the main problem that I'm trying to solve is fetch the `title` number programmatically which is in this case `628086906` that is attached to the `table_link` that I've hardcoded here.

After clicking on the tool button - in step 6 - when you hover your cursor over the map, you can see this option `Multiple` which when you click leads you to the url containing title number.

[start page](https://alta.registries.gov.ab.ca/spinii/logon.aspx)

This is exactly [the steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfKAV.jpg) the script is following.

This is the linc number `0030278592` which will be required to input in the inputbox in step 6.

I've tried with (working one as I've used hardcoded title number within `table_link`):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://alta.registries.gov.ab.ca/spinii/logon.aspx'
lnotice = 'https://alta.registries.gov.ab.ca/spinii/legalnotice.aspx'
search_page = 'https://alta.registries.gov.ab.ca/SpinII/SearchSelectType.aspx'
map_page = 'http://alta.registries.gov.ab.ca/SpinII/mapindex.aspx'
map_find = 'http://alta.registries.gov.ab.ca/SpinII/mapfinds.aspx'
table_link = 'https://alta.registries.gov.ab.ca/SpinII/popupTitleSearch.aspx?title=628086906'

def get_content(s,link):   
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
    payload['uctrlLogon:cmdLogonGuest.x'] = '80'
    payload['uctrlLogon:cmdLogonGuest.y'] = '20'

    r = s.post(link,data=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
    payload['cmdYES.x'] = '52'
    payload['cmdYES.y'] = '8'

    s.post(lnotice,data=payload)
    s.headers['Referer'] = 'https://alta.registries.gov.ab.ca/spinii/welcomeguest.aspx'
    
    s.get(search_page)
    s.headers['Referer'] = 'https://alta.registries.gov.ab.ca/SpinII/SearchSelectType.aspx'
    
    s.get(map_page)
    
    r = s.get(map_find)
    s.headers['Referer'] = 'http://alta.registries.gov.ab.ca/SpinII/mapfinds.aspx'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
    payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'Finds$lstFindTypes'
    payload['Finds:lstFindTypes'] = 'Linc'
    payload['Finds:ctlLincNumber:txtLincNumber'] = '0030278592'
    
    r = s.post(map_find,data=payload)
    
    r = s.get(table_link)
    print(r.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36'
        get_content(s,link)
```

> How can I grab the title number from the url?

or

> How can I fetch all the linc numbers from that site so that I don't need to use map at all?

`The only problem with this site is that it is unavailable in daytime for maintenance.`

Comment: Requests and BeautifulSoup are not able to render dynamic (javascript) elements.

In this case you would need to use a webdriver, like Selenium.

Selenium controls the browser, which means it is able to load the JS elements you need to scrape, and even store it's content on a variable for you to use on the script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data is called from :

```
POST http://alta.registries.gov.ab.ca/SpinII/mapserver.aspx
```

The content is encoded in a custom format before being consumed by [OpenLayers library](https://openlayers.org/). All the decoding is located in [this JS file](http://alta.registries.gov.ab.ca/SpinII/script/WayTo.Map.js). If you beautify it, you can look for the decoding it's `WayTo.Wtb.Format.WTB`'s `OpenLayers.Class`. The binary is decoded byte by byte like the following in JS :

```javascript
switch(elementType){
    case 1:
        var lineColor = new WayTo.Wtb.Element.LineColor();
        byteOffset = lineColor.parse(dataReader, byteOffset);
        outputElement = lineColor;
        break;
    case 2:
        var lineStyle = new WayTo.Wtb.Element.LineStyle();
        byteOffset = lineStyle.parse(dataReader, byteOffset);
        outputElement = lineStyle;
        break;
    case 3:
        var ellipse = new WayTo.Wtb.Element.Ellipse();
        byteOffset = ellipse.parse(dataReader, byteOffset);
        outputElement = ellipse;
        break;
    ........
}
```

We have to reproduce this decoding algorithm in order to get the raw data. We don't need to decode all the objects, we only want to get the offset right and extract the `strings` correctly. Here is a [python](/questions/tagged/python) script for the decoding part which decodes the data from a file (output of [curl](/questions/tagged/curl)):

```
with open("wtb.bin", mode='rb') as file:
    encodedData = file.read()
    offset = 0
    objects = []

    while offset < len(encodedData):

        elementSize = encodedData[offset]
        offset+=1
        elementType = encodedData[offset]
        offset+=1

        if elementType == 0:
            break

        curElemSize = elementSize
        curElemType = elementType

        if elementType== 114:
            largeElementSize = int.from_bytes(encodedData[offset:offset + 4], "big")
            offset+=4
            largeElementType = int.from_bytes(encodedData[offset:offset+2], "little")
            offset+=2
            curElemSize = largeElementSize
            curElemType = largeElementType

        print(f"type {curElemType} | size {curElemSize}")
        offsetInit = offset

        if curElemType == 1:
            offset+=4
        elif curElemType == 2:
            offset+=2
        elif curElemType == 3:
            offset+=20
        elif curElemType == 4:
            offset+=28
        elif curElemType == 5:
            offset+=12
        elif curElemType == 6:
            textLength = curElemSize - 3
            objects.append({
                "type": "Text",
                "x_position": int.from_bytes(encodedData[offset:offset+2], "little"),
                "y_position": int.from_bytes(encodedData[offset+2:offset+4], "little"),
                "rotation": int.from_bytes(encodedData[offset+4:offset+6], "little"),
                "text": encodedData[offset+6:offset+6+(textLength*2)].decode("utf-8").replace('\x00','')
            })
            offset+=6+(textLength*2)
        elif curElemType == 7:
            numPoint = int(curElemSize / 2)
            offset+=4*numPoint
        elif curElemType == 27:
            numPoint = int(curElemSize / 4)
            offset+=8*numPoint
        elif curElemType == 8:
            numPoint = int(curElemSize / 2)
            offset+=4*numPoint
        elif curElemType == 28:
            numPoint = int(curElemSize / 4)
            offset+=8*numPoint
        elif curElemType == 13:
            offset+=4
        elif curElemType == 14:
            offset+=2
        elif curElemType == 15:
            offset+=2
        elif curElemType == 100:
            pass
        elif curElemType == 101:
            offset+=20
        elif curElemType == 102:
            offset+=2
        elif curElemType == 103:
            pass
        elif curElemType == 104:
            highShort = int.from_bytes(encodedData[offset+2:offset+4], "little")
            lowShort = int.from_bytes(encodedData[offset+4:offset+6], "little")
            objects.append({
                "type": "StartNumericCell",
                "entity": int.from_bytes(encodedData[offset:offset+2], "little"),
                "occurrence": (highShort << 16) + lowShort
            })
            offset+=6
        elif curElemType == 105:
            #end cell
            pass
        elif curElemType == 109:
            textLength = curElemSize - 1
            objects.append({
                "type": "StartAlphanumericCell",
                "entity": int.from_bytes(encodedData[offset:offset+2], "little"),
                "occurrence":encodedData[offset+2:offset+2+(textLength*2)].decode("utf-8").replace('\x00','')
            })
            offset+=2+(textLength*2)
        elif curElemType == 111:
            offset+=40
        elif curElemType == 112:
            objects.append({
                "type": "CoordinatePlane",
                "projection_code": encodedData[offset+48:offset+52].decode("utf-8").replace('\x00','')
            })
            offset+=52
        elif curElemType == 113:
            offset+=24
        elif curElemType == 256:
            nameLength = int.from_bytes(encodedData[offset+14:offset+16], "little")
            objects.append({
                "type": "LargePolygon",
                "name": encodedData[offset+16:offset+16+nameLength].decode("utf-8").replace('\x00',''),
                "occurence": int.from_bytes(encodedData[offset+2:offset+6], "little")
            })
            if nameLength > 0:
                offset+= 16 + nameLength
                if encodedData[offset] == 0:
                    offset+=1
            else:
                offset+= 16
            numberOfPoints = int.from_bytes(encodedData[offset:offset+2], "little")
            offset+=2
            offset+=numberOfPoints*8
        elif curElemType == 257:
            pass
        else:
            offset+= curElemSize*2
        print(f"offset diff {offset-offsetInit}")
        print("--------------------------------")

    print(objects)
    print(len(encodedData))
    print(offset)
```

(Sidenote: note that element size is in big endian and all other values are in little endian)

Run [this repl.it](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/decodeWtb#main.py) to see how it decodes the file

From there we build the steps to scrape the data, I will describe all the steps (even those you've already figured out) for the sake of clarity :

#### Login

login to the website using :

```
GET https://alta.registries.gov.ab.ca/spinii/logon.aspx
```

scrape the input name/value and add `uctrlLogon:cmdLogonGuest.x` and `uctrlLogon:cmdLogonGuest.y` then call

```
POST https://alta.registries.gov.ab.ca/spinii/logon.aspx
```

### Legal Notice

The legal notice call is not necessary to get the map values but is necessary to get the item info (last step in your post)

```
GET https://alta.registries.gov.ab.ca/spinii/legalnotice.aspx
```

Scrape the `input` tag name/value and set `cmdYES.x` and `cmdYES.y` and then call

```
POST https://alta.registries.gov.ab.ca/spinii/legalnotice.aspx
```

#### Map data

Call the server map API :

```
POST http://alta.registries.gov.ab.ca/SpinII/mapserver.aspx
```

with the following data :

```
{
    "mt":"titleresults",
    "qt":"lincNo",
    "LINCNumber": lincNumber,
    "rights": "B", #not required
    "cx": 1920, #screen definition
    "cy": 1080,
}
```

`cx`/`xy` are canvas size

Decode the encoded data by using the method above. You will get :

```
[{'type': 'LargePolygon', 'name': '0010495134 8722524;1;162', 'entity': 23, 'occurence': 628079167, 'line_color_green': 0, 'line_color_red': 129, 'line_color_blue': 129, 'fill_color_green': 255, 'fill_color_red': 255, 'fill_color_blue': 180}, {'type': 'LargePolygon', 'name': '0012170859 8022146;8;99', 'entity': 23, 'occurence': 628048595, 'line_color_green': 0, 'line_color_red': 129, 'line_color_blue': 129, 'fill_color_green': 255, 'fill_color_red': 255, 'fill_color_blue': 180}, {'type': 'LargePolygon', 'name': '0010691822 8722524;1;163', 'entity': 23, 'occurence': 628222354, 'line_color_green': 0, 'line_color_red': 129, 'line_color_blue': 129, 'fill_color_green': 255, 'fill_color_red': 255, 'fill_color_blue': 180}, {'type': 'LargePolygon', 'name': '0012169736 8022146;8;89', 'entity': 23, 'occurence': 628021327, 'line_color_green': 0, 'line_color_red': 129, 'line_color_blue': 129, 'fill_color_green': 255, 'fill_color_red': 255, 'fill_color_blue': 180}, {'type': 'LargePolygon', 'name': '0010694454 8722524;1;179', 'entity': 23, 'occurence': 628191678, 'line_color_green': 0, 'line_color_red': 129, 'line_color_blue': 129, 'fill_color_green': 255, 'fill_color_red': 255, 'fill_color_blue': 180}, {'type': 'LargePolygon', 'name': '0010694362 8722524;1;178', 'entity': 23, 'occurence': 628307403, 'line_color_green': 0, 'line_color_red': 129, 'line_color_blue': 129, 'fill_color_green': 255, 'fill_color_red': 255, 'fill_color_blue': 180}, {'type': 'LargePolygon', 'name': '0010433381 8722524;1;177', 'entity': 23, 'occurence': 628209696, 'line_color_green': 0, 'line_color_red': 129, 'line_color_blue': 129, 'fill_color_green': 255, 'fill_color_red': 255, 'fill_color_blue': 180}, {'type': 'LargePolygon', 'name': '0012169710 8022146;8;88A', 'entity': 23, 'occurence': 628021328, 'line_color_green': 0, 'line_color_red': 129, 'line_color_blue': 129, 'fill_color_green': 255, 'fill_color_red': 255, 'fill_color_blue': 180}, {'type': 'LargePolygon', 'name': '0010694355 8722524;1;176', 'entity': 23, 'occurence': 628315826, 'line_color_green': 0, 'line_color_red': 129, 'line_color_blue': 129, 'fill_color_green': 255, 'fill_color_red': 255, 'fill_color_blue': 180}, {'type': 'LargePolygon', 'name': '0012170866 8022146;8;100', 'entity': 23, 'occurence': 628163431, 'line_color_green': 0, 'line_color_red': 129, 'line_color_blue': 129, 'fill_color_green': 255, 'fill_color_red': 255, 'fill_color_blue': 180}, {'type': 'LargePolygon', 'name': '0010694347 8722524;1;175', 'entity': 23, 'occurence': 628132810, 'line_color_green': 0, 'line_color_red': 129,
```

#### Extract the info

If you want to target a specific `lincNumber` you will need to look for the style of the polygon since for "multiple" values (eg values with multiple items) there are no mention of the `lincNumber` id the response, just a link reference. The following will get the selected item :

```
selectedZone = [
    t 
    for t in objects 
    if t.get("fill_color_green", 255) < 255 and t.get("line_color_red") == 255
][0]
print(selectedZone)
```

Call the url you mention in your post to get the data and extract the table :

```
GET https://alta.registries.gov.ab.ca/SpinII/popupTitleSearch.aspx?title={selectedZone["occurence"]}
```

The full code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

lincNumber = "0030278592"
#lincNumber = "0010661156"

s = requests.Session()

# 1) login
r = s.get("https://alta.registries.gov.ab.ca/spinii/logon.aspx")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

payload = dict([
    (t["name"], t.get("value", ""))
    for t in soup.findAll("input")
])
payload["uctrlLogon:cmdLogonGuest.x"] = 76
payload["uctrlLogon:cmdLogonGuest.y"] = 25
s.post("https://alta.registries.gov.ab.ca/spinii/logon.aspx",data=payload)

# 2) legal notice
r = s.get("https://alta.registries.gov.ab.ca/spinii/legalnotice.aspx")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
payload = dict([
    (t["name"], t.get("value", ""))
    for t in soup.findAll("input")
])
payload["cmdYES.x"] = 82
payload["cmdYES.y"] = 3
s.post("https://alta.registries.gov.ab.ca/spinii/legalnotice.aspx", data = payload)

# 3) map data
r = s.post("http://alta.registries.gov.ab.ca/SpinII/mapserver.aspx",
    data= {
        "mt":"titleresults",
        "qt":"lincNo",
        "LINCNumber": lincNumber,
        "rights": "B", #not required
        "cx": 1920, #screen definition
        "cy": 1080,
    })

def decodeWtb(encodedData):
    offset = 0

    objects = []
    iteration = 0

    while offset < len(encodedData):

        elementSize = encodedData[offset]
        offset+=1
        elementType = encodedData[offset]
        offset+=1

        if elementType == 0:
            break

        curElemSize = elementSize
        curElemType = elementType

        if elementType== 114:
            largeElementSize = int.from_bytes(encodedData[offset:offset + 4], "big")
            offset+=4
            largeElementType = int.from_bytes(encodedData[offset:offset+2], "little")
            offset+=2
            curElemSize = largeElementSize
            curElemType = largeElementType

        offsetInit = offset

        if curElemType == 1:
            offset+=4
        elif curElemType == 2:
            offset+=2
        elif curElemType == 3:
            offset+=20
        elif curElemType == 4:
            offset+=28
        elif curElemType == 5:
            offset+=12
        elif curElemType == 6:
            textLength = curElemSize - 3
            offset+=6+(textLength*2)
        elif curElemType == 7:
            numPoint = int(curElemSize / 2)
            offset+=4*numPoint
        elif curElemType == 27:
            numPoint = int(curElemSize / 4)
            offset+=8*numPoint
        elif curElemType == 8:
            numPoint = int(curElemSize / 2)
            offset+=4*numPoint
        elif curElemType == 28:
            numPoint = int(curElemSize / 4)
            offset+=8*numPoint
        elif curElemType == 13:
            offset+=4
        elif curElemType == 14:
            offset+=2
        elif curElemType == 15:
            offset+=2
        elif curElemType == 100:
            pass
        elif curElemType == 101:
            offset+=20
        elif curElemType == 102:
            offset+=2
        elif curElemType == 103:
            pass
        elif curElemType == 104:
            offset+=6
        elif curElemType == 105:
            pass
        elif curElemType == 109:
            textLength = curElemSize - 1
            offset+=2+(textLength*2)
        elif curElemType == 111:
            offset+=40
        elif curElemType == 112:
            offset+=52
        elif curElemType == 113:
            offset+=24
        elif curElemType == 256:
            nameLength = int.from_bytes(encodedData[offset+14:offset+16], "little")
            objects.append({
                "type": "LargePolygon",
                "name": encodedData[offset+16:offset+16+nameLength].decode("utf-8").replace('\x00',''),
                "entity": int.from_bytes(encodedData[offset:offset+2], "little"),
                "occurence": int.from_bytes(encodedData[offset+2:offset+6], "little"),
                "line_color_green": encodedData[offset + 8],
                "line_color_red": encodedData[offset + 7],
                "line_color_blue": encodedData[offset + 9],
                "fill_color_green": encodedData[offset + 10],
                "fill_color_red": encodedData[offset + 11],
                "fill_color_blue": encodedData[offset + 13]
            })
            if nameLength > 0:
                offset+= 16 + nameLength
                if encodedData[offset] == 0:
                    offset+=1
            else:
                offset+= 16
            numberOfPoints = int.from_bytes(encodedData[offset:offset+2], "little")
            offset+=2
            offset+=numberOfPoints*8
        elif curElemType == 257:
            pass
        else:
            offset+= curElemSize*2

    return objects

# 4) decode custom format
objects = decodeWtb(r.content)

# 5) get the selected area
selectedZone = [
    t 
    for t in objects 
    if t.get("fill_color_green", 255) < 255 and t.get("line_color_red") == 255
][0]
print(selectedZone)

# 6) get the info about item
r = s.get(f'https://alta.registries.gov.ab.ca/SpinII/popupTitleSearch.aspx?title={selectedZone["occurence"]}')
df = pd.read_html(r.content, attrs = {'class': 'bodyText'}, header =0)[0]
del df['Add to Cart']
del df['View']
print(df[:-1])
```

[Run this on repl.it](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/ScrapeWtbOpenLayerData)

Output

```
  Title Number           Type LINC Number Short Legal   Rights Registration Date Change/Cancel Date
0    052400228  Current Title  0030278592  0420091;16  Surface        19/09/2005         13/11/2019
1    072294084  Current Title  0030278551  0420091;12  Surface        22/05/2007         21/08/2007
2    072400529  Current Title  0030278469   0420091;3  Surface        05/07/2007         28/08/2007
3    072498228  Current Title  0030278501   0420091;7  Surface        18/08/2007         08/02/2008
4    072508699  Current Title  0030278535  0420091;10  Surface        23/08/2007         13/12/2007
5    072559500  Current Title  0030278477   0420091;4  Surface        17/09/2007         19/11/2007
6    072559508  Current Title  0030278576  0420091;14  Surface        17/09/2007         09/01/2009
7    072559521  Current Title  0030278519   0420091;8  Surface        17/09/2007         07/11/2007
8    072559530  Current Title  0030278493   0420091;6  Surface        17/09/2007         25/08/2008
9    072559605  Current Title  0030278485   0420091;5  Surface        17/09/2007         23/12/2008
```

You can look at the `objects` field if you want to get more entries. And you can improve the decoder if you want to get more info about item like coordinates etc...

It's also possible to match the other lincNumber located around your target by looking at the `name` field which contains the lincNumber unless there is a "multiple" name in it.

fun fact :

> no http header need to be set in this flow

Comment: Thanks for your solution @Bertrand Martel. It works perfectly. As you have combed through the map, you might have noticed whether it is possible to grab all the linc numbers from there. I just wish to know whether it is possible at all. I'll award the bounty when time is right as your solution seems to be attracting attention of the viewers. Thanks.

Comment: @robots.txt To get all the values, I suppose you would need to use `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2` parameters in the data endpoint. You can have a static value for y1 and y2 and then  requesting x1 + 4000 / x2 + 4000 etc... You would need to exclude the duplicates. But there will still be the "multiple" values that you can't extract from the map, for them you will need to perform the flow above. The good news is that the data endpoint is public, so you don't need to login/legal notice endpoint etc... to get those values but it will be required for "Mulitple" values

Comment: @robots.txt for example see [this repl.it](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/WtbMapRequest) which downloads data spaced with x1+4000/x2+4000 in a dense area, remove duplicates and shows number of "multiple" requests that will need to be sent

Comment: I know you have spent a lot of time on this post and surely came up with successful results. However, I was trying to fetch most of the linc numbers from that map. I tried to abide by your suggestion to get it done but perhaps I went somewhere wrong. Given that I incremented the value of `x1` and `y1` by 4300 in every loop and found success in few attempts and then the script can't add new linc numbers. This is my ***[current attempt](https://pastebin.com/yjJUCAzd)***. Is there any way I can get most of the linc numbers? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to get info you are looking for where one is selenium that you probably already know.

Open netwok tab and monitor requests being passed by browser when you hover over the map if requests are made to server or not. Your best bet with requests and BS4 is if data is already loaded than solution below might work

```
import re 
print(re.findall(r’628086906’, r.text) )
```

if it prints out the number it means data is available in json and loaded with page you can either load json or find using regex. Otherwise your only option is selenium

Comment: There are other ways to check the availability of that number using chrome dev tools which is more reliable than the way you suggested. For example, the number may be within any json response which your suggested approach won't grab from. However, I didn't find that number using the steps I just told you. In my experience I have noticed that there are hardly any sites from where it is not possible to grab data using requests module. I just could not reverse engineer in the right way. That's it.

Comment: I am sure there are, regex is the quickest method in my opinion to get anything out of json loaded in websites. You are right here you can get anything using requests this is what browsers do. I am following this question i hope you ge the answer you are looking for and i too learn something new.